# Why is it "while kill -0 $PID" and not "until kill -0 $PID"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting, exit

I may be being daft here, but if I want to do something while a process is running, why do I do:

```
while kill -0 $PID
do
    #...
done
```

instead of

```
until kill -0 $PID
do
    #...
done
```

?

`kill -0` exits with code `1` if the process is not found, and `0` if the process is found:

```
$ kill -0 123444
-bash: kill: (123444) - No such process
$ echo $?
1
$ screen -ls | grep rofl
    28043.rofl  (02/19/2015 02:27:56 PM)    (Detached)
$ kill -0 28043
$ echo $?
0
```

So if the process is running, wouldn't the while loop boil down to:

```
while 0
do
    #...
done
```

which would then never execute?

Comment: The shell is not `C`, though it was originally written by the same people.

Comment: You might want to use `pgrep` or `ps` instead of `kill` to check if a process is running, e.g. `while pgrep apt; do sleep 1; done; notify-send "Package installation complete."`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When dealing with return codes "0" is a success and non-zero is failure. The syntax of a while loop is:

```
while COMMANDS; do ...; done
```

The `while` statement checks the return code of the last command in the provided list of commands. In you last example of `while 0`, this will attempt to execute a command called "0" and check it's return code.

A literal 0 is not special to bash outside of arithmetic context. Inside of that context, 0 *is* considered false. For example

```
while (( 0 )); do
  ... # never executes
end
```

This case is special as the keyword `((` is treated as a command, which returns non-zero because it's result is 0.

Answer (score 5):

The shell does not expanded condition like you think.

In shell, an error code `0` indicated that the command has completed successfully. Any non-zero error code indicated that there was error.

For more concisely, POSIX define [while loop](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_09) as:

> The while loop shall continuously execute one compound-list as long as
>   another compound-list has a zero exit status.
>
> The format of the while loop is as follows:

```
while compound-list-1
do
    compound-list-2
done
```

> The compound-list-1 shall be executed, and if it has a non-zero exit
>   status, the while command shall complete. Otherwise, the
>   compound-list-2 shall be executed, and the process shall repeat.

Answer (score 5):

The "while" command isn't looking for a boolean value, it's looking for a return code of "0" which indicates successful execution of the command. So in the case the while command, a command that returns 0 is "true" and anything else is "false".

Even when you're doing a comparison, Bash treats that like a command which is returning a successful error code (0) when the comparison is true.

Answer (score 2):

The exit code is not a boolean value, is an integer, by convention the zero value is success, so you are thinking in negative logic from Bash's point of view